# Phalcon - add option to select

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm creating search engine and i want to create select with all providers of an item by

controller:

```
$this->view->providers = Provider::find(["order"=>"name"]);
```

view:

```
{{ select("searchProvider", providers, "class":"form-control", "using":["id", "name"]) }}
```

but how to add to this select "all providers" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using Volt tag helpers, then the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to add three new arguments to the select() function:

`{{ select("searchProvider", providers, "class":"form-control", "using":["id", "name"], "useEmpty":true, "emptyText":"all providers", "emptyValue":"") }}`

Here you are designating an 'empty' select option with the text that you want and an empty value. Then in your controller, you can execute code depending on whether `searchProvider` is empty or not. Just be very careful with those values returned in the form. But form validation and sanitation is another topic.